# Is the following equation solvable by Mathematica?

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve and plot the solutions of the following equation, where Mathematica is still running and doesn't return anything:

```
Solve[Rationalize[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.409)), 0] == 0, b]
ListPlot[ReIm[b /. % /. C[1] -> 0], ImageSize -> Large, PlotRange -> {{-0.8, 1.9}, {-500, 500}}]
```

where $b$ is complex. Is there any other method to try here?

Comment: To find only a single root, you could try FindRoot: "FindRoot[E^(-b (1365/1000)) + E^(-b (-350/1000)) + 
  E^(-b (-409/1000)), {b, I}]"

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue it raises is not really a Mathematica issue but a matter of the OP not having grasped the relevant mathematics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following (`NSolve` instead of `Solve`) works.

```
NSolve[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.409)) == 0, b];
ListPlot[ReIm[b /. % /. C[1] -> 0], ImageSize -> Large, 
PlotRange -> {{-0.8, 1.9}, {-500, 500}}]
```

[image]

Comment: `NSolve[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.409)) == 0 && 
  Im[b] == 0, b]` results in `{}` so there is no real solution.

Comment: What do you mean as " close to the real axis"?

Comment: `NSolve[E^(-b (1.365)) + E^(-b (-0.350)) + E^(-b (-0.409)) == 0 && 
  Im[b] <= 1 && Im[b] >= -1 && Re[b] < 100 && Re[b] > -100, b]` also performs `{}`.

Comment: @Amancalledanoldfashion  In fact, because the equation is a sum of exponentials, it cannot be solved by any real `b`.